# Tkinter window is still not appearing

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a simple tkinter GUI, and have read up online to add a .mainloop() to the end of my code to make the window appear, It is still not appearing.

There is no error message and simply

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

I have attached my code.

Any help is greatly appreciated

```
def window():
    global FPS
    global maxFPS
    root = Tk()
    root.title('Camera Tracker')
    root.geometry('500x300')

def quitfunc():

    quitm=Tk()
    quitm.title('Quit')
    quitm.geometry('200x100')

    yesbutton=Button(quitm,text='Yes',command=quit)
    nobutton =Button(quitm,text='No',command=quitm.destroy)

    yesbutton.place(x=50,y=60)
    nobutton.place(x=130,y=60)
    reassure = Label(quitm,text='Are you sure you want to quit?')
    reassure.place(x=17,y=20)

    quitm.mainloop()

sbview = Label(root, text=FPS)
sbview.place(y=50, x=50)

def FPScallback(self):
    global FPS
    FPS = round(sb.get())
    if 10 > FPS < 18 or 29 < FPS:
        sbview.config(fg='orange')
    elif FPS < 10:
        sbview.config(fg='red')
    else:
        sbview.config(fg='green')
    sbview.config(text=FPS)

quitbutton = Button(root,command=quitfunc,text='Quit')
quitbutton.pack()

sb = ttk.Scale(root, from_=0, to=maxFPS, command=FPScallback, orient=HORIZONTAL)
sb.place(y=100, x=100)
sb.set(FPS)

root.mainloop()
```

Thanks A Bunch In Advance

Comment: Change your code following this pattern: [tkinter-hello-again](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-hello-again.htm)

Comment: Is this the actual indentation of your code?

Comment: You're defining your `root` in the `window` function, but you never call it...

Answer (score 0):

If you create `root` from inside a function it will not be available when the function exits. In my example I'm creating root as well as some global variables in the global scope.

To ask the user if he wants to exit it's easier to use the standard library `messagebox`. If you want to catch any attempt to close the application (such as <kbd>ALT-F4</kbd>) you should reasearch `root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", do_exit)` which runs the `do_exit` function when the app wants to exit by any means.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox  # Quit dialog

root = Tk()                     # Create root in the global scope 
root.title('Camera Tracker')    # so the functions can find it 
root.geometry('500x300')

maxFPS = 50     # Initiate variables in the global scope
FPS = 25

sbview = Label(root, text=FPS)
sbview.place(y=50, x=50)

def quitfunc():
    result = messagebox.askyesno('Quit', 'Are you sure you want to quit?')
    if result:
        root.destroy()

def FPScallback(self):
    global FPS
    FPS = round(sb.get())
    if 10 > FPS < 18 or 29 < FPS:
        sbview.config(fg='orange')
    elif FPS < 10:
        sbview.config(fg='red')
    else:
        sbview.config(fg='green')
    sbview.config(text=FPS)

sb = ttk.Scale(root, from_=0, to=maxFPS, command=FPScallback, orient=HORIZONTAL)
sb.place(y=100, x=100)
sb.set(FPS)

quitbutton = Button(root, command=quitfunc, text='Quit')
quitbutton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```